# Angular translate get language from localstorage

Tags: angularjs, local-storage, angular-translate

I'm using Angular Translate in a project. The chosen language is saved using `useLocalStorage()` and it's working fine.

But I want to get the language is used/choosen. Before I was using local storage `$translate.use` was working fine, but now `$translate.use` is undefined.

Is there a way to get the actual language from the localstorage?

Answer (score 1):

The function `$translate.use()` is both a setter and a getter. Try this:

```
var $userLanguage = $translate.proposedLanguage() || $translate.use();
```

If `proposedLanguage()` is undefined, the return value of `use()` will be assigned to `$userLanguage`.

Based on your question, maybe you just forgot the brackets?